# Is $x^2 + 1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}/_{3}[x]$?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, finite-rings

**My Problem is** to consider if the polynomial $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{/3}[x]$

**My Approach was:** after looking closer onto the given Facts, i can see that $\mathbb{Z}/_{3}[x]$ is a polynomial ring that consists of:
$$\mathbb{Z}/_{3}[x]=\{ 0, 1, 2, x, x+1, x+2, 2x, 2x+1, 2x+2 \} $$
On the other Hand, the given polynomial can be transformed into: 
$$x^2 + 1 = (x+1)\cdot (x+1)$$ 
And due to $(x+1)\in \mathbb{Z}/_{3}[x]$ i can state that the given polynomial is actually not irreducible.

**My question is:** am i right? And in case i am wrong, what are my mistakes?

**Post scriptum:** as i was told in the comments, i made some mistakes. $\sqrt{x^2 +1}$ has no root in the given ring, so the polynomial is in fact irreducible.

Comment: Is $x^2 + 1$ really equal to $(x + 1)(x + 1)$?

Comment: You forgot the element $2$ in your enumeration of $\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z}[x]$. As Henry Swanson said, you equality is also wrong. As your polynomial is of degree 2, if it is reducible, it is the product of two polynomials of degree one, and therefore, it has at least one root. But $0^2+1\neq0$, $1^2+1\neq0$ and $2^2+1\neq 0$.

Comment: Remember that a polynomial of degree $2$ or $3$ over a field is reducible if *and only if* it has a root in the field. (The only if part is no longeer true in higher degrees.) So when working over a small finite field it is completely straightforward to check if such a polynomial is irreducible: test all the elements of the field to see if you can find a root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Test if $x^2+1$ vanishes for some $x \in \mathbb F_3$. If it does, then it is a product of linear factors. If not, then it cannot be reducible.

Comment: I can see now, that $\sqrt{x^2 +1}$ has no Root in in $\mathbb{Z}_{/3}[x]$ ..(in fact it might be a complex root) I made a mistake in my equation. There is no root and thats why it is irreducible? right?

Comment: @ToralfWestström Yes, there is no root. If it were reducible, it would be a product of two linear polynomials, so it would have a root.